# Confusion with generics, java

Tags: java, generics

I have generic class :

```
public class Test<T> {

    private Test<? extends T> myInstance;

    public Test<? extends T> getInstance () {
      return myInstance;
    }

    public void setInstance (Test<? extends T> argType) {
        this.myInstance = argType;
    }

}
```

And I have two classes in my class hierarchy relations:

```
public abstract class Alphabet {
    //code here
}
```

and

```
public class A extends Alphabet{

   public A() {
       super();
       System.out.print("This is A call");
   }
}
```

Finally I have a class where I want to store make generic class Test with particular type and set new Instance of Object  -> A through `setInstance()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Alphabet> list = new ArrayList<Alphabet>();

        Test<Alphabet> tAlphabet = new Test<Alphabet>();
        tAlphabet.setInstance(new A()); //Here is compilation ERROR
}
```

But I have got the compilation error in line `tAlphabet.setInstance(new A());`

What is the issue with my generic class?

Comment: `A` extends `Alphabet`, but `setInstance` requires an instance of `Test`.

Comment: `Test<? extends T>` represents an instance of `Test` with a generic type argument which extends `T`. So, for example, an instance of `Test<A>` is an instance of `Test<? extends T>` as `A` extends `T` (which is `Alphabet`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance is a `Test` object as it's currently written, and you are supplying it with an `Alphabet` object instead. You probably want your instance to be of type `Alphabet`:

```
public class Test<T> {
    private T myInstance;

    public T getInstance() {
        return myInstance;
    }

    public void setInstance(T argType) {
        myInstance = argType;
    }
}
```

This way, your `Test` stores an `Alphabet` instead of another `Test`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have made things more complicated than needed. You probably want this in your Test class instead of what you actually have:

```
private T myInstance;

public T getInstance () {
  return myInstance;
}

public void setInstance (T argType) {
  this.myInstance = argType;
}
```

With this arrangement you would be free to `setInstance(new A())` on a `Test<Alphabet>` instance.

Comment: Hm?As I understands the Test(in my case) can take and became type of generic passed to it, in my case is Alphabet, since in setInstance method type of argument Test<? extends T> argType can be any type of T - Alphabet and his subtypes, then I expect it to handle new A() normaly? Am I right?

Comment: Can you just explain why you accepted the answer virtually identical to this one, whereas you are asking here about its correctness? Perhaps you have worked it out in the meantime?

Comment: Yes. I've got understand the issue from the question above. thank you for your answers. My comment was a head of time to you. Thank you.